# Settings options not showing up on Sub Menu page in WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, sub-menu

So I have a plugin with two user-customisable settings. (It's not complete but I'm getting the framework in place.)  When the two settings are on the "general" settings page they work just fine...

```
add_action('admin_init', 'mj_admin_init');
function mj_admin_init(){
    register_setting('general', 'mj_options', 'mj_validate_input');
    add_settings_section('mjid', 'MJ Settings', 'mj_callback', 'general');
    add_settings_field('mj_notify_email', 'Email', 'mj_email_input', 'general', 'mjid');
    add_settings_field('mj_cm_enabled', 'Enable Messages', 'mj_cm_enabled_input', 'general', 'mjid');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'mj_admin_menu');
function mj_admin_menu(){
    do_settings_sections('mjid');
}

function mj_admin(){
    // to-do later
}

function mj_callback(){
    echo '<p>MJ Callback function produced this</p>';
}

function mj_email_input(){
    $options = get_option('mj_options');
    $value = $options['mj_email'];
    echo '<input id="mj_email" name="mj_options[mj_email]" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($value).'" /> <em>Email address</em>';
}

function mj_cm_enabled_input(){
    $options = get_option('mj_options');
    $value = $options['cm-enabled'];
    echo '<input id="cm-enabled" name="mj_options[cm-enabled]" type="checkbox" value=1 '.checked(1, esc_attr($value), false).' /> <em>Checkbox for enabled messages</em>';
}


function mj_validate_input($input){
    $valid = array();
    $valid['mj_email'] = sanitize_email( $input['mj_email']);
    if($valid['mj_email'] != $input['mj_email']) {
        add_settings_error('mj_email_setting', 'mj_texterror', 'Invalid email', 'error');
    }
    $valid['cm-enabled'] = intval($input['cm-enabled']);
    return $valid;
}
```

But I want to put them on a separate submenu page, called "mj-admin-settings".  But, try as I might, they won't show up.  All I get is the output of the "mj_callback" function.  There are no errors in the error logs, even with debug set to true.

To do the above I changed the `mj_admin_init` and `mj_admin_menu` functions to the following:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'mj_admin_init');
function mj_admin_init(){
    register_setting('mj-admin-settings', 'mj_options', 'mj_validate_input');
    add_settings_section('mjid', 'MJ Settings', 'mj_callback', 'mj-admin-settings');
    add_settings_field('mj_notify_email', 'Email', 'mj_email_input', 'mj-admin-settings', 'mjid');
    add_settings_field('mj_cm_enabled', 'Enable Messages', 'mj_cm_enabled_input', 'mj-admin-settings', 'mjid');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'mj_admin_menu');
function mj_admin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('MJ Admin', 'MJ Admin', 'manage_options', 'mj-admin-options', 'mj_admin');
    add_submenu_page('mj-admin-options', 'MJ Admin - Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'mj-admin-settings', 'mj_callback');

    do_settings_sections('mjid');
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I get the settings to display in the submenu please?  I've been all over the codex and am stumped!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the arguments for [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page), you'll see that the fifth argument is your callback function.  And, right now, there's nothing in the mj_admin function.

What you need to do is output your form in that function.

```
<?php
function mj_admin(){
?>
    <h2>My Settings Page</h2>
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
<?php
    settings_fields( 'mj-admin-settings' );
    do_settings_sections('mj-admin-settings');
    submit_button();
?>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Matthew, but it still doesn't work.  I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if is this the problem but when i add a sub menu page i do it in this way:

```
add_submenu_page('mj-admin-options.php', 'MJ Admin - Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'mj-admin-settings', 'mj_callback');
```

Type the slug with his php extension ;)